# Google Maps route using 300 waypoint

Tags: dictionary, path, routes

Framework: Ionic

I am using google map for displaying route in an ionic 4 mobile application.
Is there any way to make a route with 300 waypoint (latitude, longitude)
as google always showing error `MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED`

Google map is allowing upto 25 waypoints only

example:

```js
function calcRoute() {
  var waypts = [];
  prepareWaypointsArray(waypts);

  start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.943382, 6.463116);
  end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.943382, 6.463116);

  createMarker(start);

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
    }
  });
}
```

```js
function prepareWaypointsArray(waypts) {
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.943571, 6.463856);
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.945032, 6.465776);
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(51.945538, 6.469413);
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google only provides upto 25 waypoints.

I did this by receiving my 25 waypoints and breaking them up into different routes and drawing them together as the same route.

For example, I have 400 waypoints, I break them into 25 points each and passed into google DirectionsService api and draw them on the map by concatenating the path.

Working example:

```
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.long },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, myOptions);
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
    this.start = this.map.getCenter();
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: this.start,
      map: this.map,
      icon: {
        url: "assets/images/count_bg_small.png",
      },
    });
    const myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<div style="color:black"><p>My Location</p></div>',
      position: this.start,
      // pixelOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    });
    myInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, "idle", () => {
      this.main(data);
    });
    //this.polyLines(this.lat, this.long, data[0][0], data[0][1]);
    const destination = { lat: data[0][0], lng: data[0][1] };
    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(this.start, this.waypoints, destination);
  }

  main(data) {
    // initalise directions service
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var travelWaypoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; ++i) {
      travelWaypoints.push({
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0], data[i][1]),
      });
    }

    // get directions and draw on map
    this.gDirRequest(directionsService, travelWaypoints, (path) => {
      var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: "#1A66FE",
        clickable: false,
        map: this.map,
        path: path,
      });
    });

    this.makeMarkerForClassicRide(data, "first");
    this.makeMarkerForClassicRide(data, "last");
  }

  gDirRequest(service, waypoints, userFunction, waypointIndex = 0, path = []) {
    console.log("gDirRequest called");
    // set defaults
    waypointIndex = typeof waypointIndex !== "undefined" ? waypointIndex : 0;
    path = typeof path !== "undefined" ? path : [];

    // get next set of waypoints
    var s: any = this.gDirGetNextSet(waypoints, waypointIndex);

    // build request object
    var startl = s[0].shift()["location"];
    var endl = s[0].pop()["location"];
    var request = {
      origin: startl,
      destination: endl,
      waypoints: s[0],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      optimizeWaypoints: false,
      provideRouteAlternatives: false,
      avoidHighways: this.avoidHighways,
      avoidTolls: this.avoidHighways,
    };
    console.log(request);
    service.route(request, (response, status) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(status);
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        path = path.concat(response.routes[0].overview_path);

        if (s[1] != null) {
          console.log("...........gDirRequest....>>>>");
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.gDirRequest(service, waypoints, userFunction, s[1], path);
          }, 200);
        } else {
          userFunction(path);
        }
      } else {
        console.log(status);
      }
    });
  }

  gDirGetNextSet(waypoints, startIndex) {
    console.log("gDirGetNextSet called");
    var MAX_WAYPOINTS_PER_REQUEST = 25;

    var w = []; // array of waypoints to return

    if (startIndex > waypoints.length - 1) {
      return [w, null];
    } // no more waypoints to process

    var endIndex = startIndex + MAX_WAYPOINTS_PER_REQUEST;

    // adjust waypoints, because Google allows us to include the start and destination latlongs for free!
    endIndex += 2;

    if (endIndex > waypoints.length - 1) {
      endIndex = waypoints.length;
    }

    for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
      w.push(waypoints[i]);
    }

    if (endIndex != waypoints.length) {
      return [w, (endIndex -= 1)];
    } else {
      return [w, null];
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps, as it worked for me in a practice application.